# "undefined reference" reported when performing rpmbuild on rhel8, different gcc linker behaviour on x86_64 and s390x?

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to install the mlnx ofed on rhel8 from the source (MLNX_OFED_SRC-5.0-2.1.8.0.tgz) (x86_64 and s390x respectively), the installation on x86_64 has no issues, but on s390x the installation reports "undefined reference" error.

```
+ /usr/bin/make
/usr/bin/make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory '/var/tmp/OFED_topdir/BUILD/perftest-4.4'
  CC       src/get_clock.o
In file included from /usr/include/sys/time.h:21,
                 from src/get_clock.c:43:
/usr/include/features.h:184:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]
 # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
   ^~~~~~~
  CC       src/perftest_communication.o
  CC       src/perftest_parameters.o
  CC       src/perftest_resources.o
  CC       src/perftest_counters.o
  CC       src/raw_ethernet_resources.o
  AR       libperftest.a
  CC       src/send_bw.o
  CC       src/multicast_resources.o
  CCLD     ib_send_bw
/usr/lib/gcc/s390x-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/libmlx5.a(verbs.c.o): In function `create_cq':
(.text+0x860): undefined reference to `rdmacore28_0_ibv_cmd_create_cq'
(.text+0x912): undefined reference to `rdmacore28_0_ibv_cmd_create_cq_ex'
/usr/lib/gcc/s390x-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/libmlx5.a(verbs.c.o): In function `_mlx5_create_flow_action_esp':
(.text+0x9ba): undefined reference to `rdmacore28_0_ibv_cmd_create_flow_action_esp'

......................

/usr/lib/gcc/s390x-redhat-linux/8/../../../../lib64/libmlx5.a(mlx5.c.o): In function `drv__register_driver':
(.text.startup[.text.startup.group]+0x8): undefined reference to `rdmacore28_0_verbs_register_driver_25'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Makefile:711: ib_send_bw] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/var/tmp/OFED_topdir/BUILD/perftest-4.4'
make: *** [Makefile:552: all] Error 2
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.SFtR26 (%build)
```

rpmbuild log on s390x:
 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vSF8eRPLGP9eDWgQ2wrtWvqkm1R5_B-J/view?usp=sharing

rpmbuild log on x86_64:
 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SFGwmJBgh7Y8shL75Nr5NFVhcj_aqU-V/view?usp=sharing

I checked the both nm output for the mentioned object file (/usr/lib64/libmlx5.a) on both machine, not found any difference for the "undefined symbols" mentioned in the error log.

nm output on s390x:
 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Wu9kPX2R6w2_RDlAHvyG4Qre1JUXxThz/view?usp=sharing

nm output on x86_64:
 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xCATkGjhANXakEiYnu7td7orkuWeUkee/view?usp=sharing

So, what could be the reason? different gcc linker behaviour?

Regards
FuLong

Comment: Please don't post textual stuff as images, it's easy enough just to copy in the text, select it, and press CTRL-K to indent it into a code block.

Comment: is libxmlx5.a a platform specific library ? Did you made sure you are linking to the right library for the right platform

Comment: @Soundararajan The libxmlx5.a is not a platform library, it's from another package inside the source code. i did nothing to the installation process, there is an install.pl inside the source code package, when you run the script, it will guide you through the installation process. the installation is a rpmbuild process essentially.

Comment: Ok this was a fun read to find out this was Linux on the mainframe and those rdmacore libraries appear to be libraries for Infiniband of all things. Does Linux on the mainframe use all the same drivers as regular Linux? What does IBM say about these drivers?

Comment: @West Yes, I'm trying to build the ofed driver to drive the integrated pcie RoCE adaopter on the mainframe. Normally, Linux on z has different device drivers, for example, the OSA adaptor for network access has dedicate drivers contributed from IBM development team, but for this RoCE adaptor, IBM doesn't provide dedicate drivers, so i want to make a try for open souce implementation and so far i can tell most of the driver packages i can successfully rebuild on the mainframe lpar.  thanks!

Comment: Does anyone has any idea for this? Appreciate if any clue!